# How i delete float 2D array in c++, with QT

Tags: c++, arrays, image, qt, opencv3.0

Hi I'm using QT to my work and i can't delete a 2D float array from memory.
I'm working with images, so I need delete arrays for not consume much memory.
I tried this way but doesn't work:

```
int n = test.cols; // number of colums image.
int m = test.rows; // number of lines image
float soma[test.cols][test.rows]; // create a array 2D for operations...

for(int i = 0 ; i < n + 2 ; ++i)
{
 for(int j = 0 ; j < m + 2 ; ++j) delete[] soma[i][j] ;
 delete[] soma[i];
}
delete[] soma;
```

Comment: Were you able to compile and build your program using the posted code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case the array is either on the STACK or in the DATA section of memory, not the HEAP. Only memory in the HEAP that is allocated with new[] can be deleted by the delete[] operator.

Not this example creates a series of *discontinuous* rows all over memory.

If you allocated the memory like this.

```
float ** soma = new float* [test.rows];
// WARNING UNITIALIZED CONTENT
for(int i = 0 ; i < test.rows; ++i) soma[i] = new float[test.cols];
```

You could then delete the memory like this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < test.rows; ++i) delete [] soma[i];
delete [] soma;
```

However it is often better to allocate a single continuous image (if the dimensions are not too big). You then use a second array to record row offsets as pointers.

```
// WARNING UNITIALIZED CONTENT
float * buffer = new float [ test.rows * test.cols ]
float ** soma = new float* [ test.rows ];
for(int i = 0 ; i < m; ++i) soma[i] = soma + i * test.cols;
```

Then delete it like this

```
delete [] soma;
delete [] buffer;
```

Or just use std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Thx, i use std::vector, i'm working with images, static allocation is not a good way, so i use std::vector, for this work, Thank you for your attention,  , follow my code now:

```
   vector <float> lines(test.rows);
   vector<vector<float> > colums(test.cols,lines);



   for(int i=0;i<colums.size(); i++) {
      for (int j=0;j<colums[i].size(); j++){


          colums[i][j]  = ((float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0]/(float)(imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0] + (float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i) [1]  +  (float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i) [2]))*255;
          aux      = (int) floor(colums[i][j] + 0.5);
          colums[i][j]  = aux;
          test.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[0] = aux;
          aux = 0;




                colums[i][j]  = ((float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[1]/
                                (float)(imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0] +
                                (float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i) [1]  +
                                (float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i) [2]))*255;

                aux      = (int) floor(colums[i][j] + 0.5);
                colums[i][j]  = aux;
                test.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[1] = aux;
                aux = 0;


                            colums[i][j]  = ((float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[2]/
                                             (float)(imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0]  +
                                             (float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i) [1]  +
                                             (float)imagem.at<Vec3b>(j,i) [2]))*255;

                            aux      = (int) floor(colums[i][j] + 0.5);
                            colums[i][j]  = aux;
                            test.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[2] = aux;
                            aux = 0;




      }

   }
```